# gh-pages doesn't show my site (don't find index.js)

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

This is happening in two projects:
https://nazarenoalt.github.io/curriculum-maker/
https://nazarenoalt.github.io/react-shop/

in the two cases the page is blank and the console says:

```
GET https://nazarenoalt.github.io/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Note that is looking for index.js/bundle.js in the root folder

In the two cases the package.json is correctly configured

```
"homepage": "https://nazarenoalt.github.io/curriculum-maker/",
```

And the two sites are configured to render the page in gh-pages branch.

As a way to solve this I tried to add HashRoute of react-router-dom as say someone in internet, but it didn't work too. (in the first page, where originally didn't use Router)

Comment: `npm run deploy` will do it, check settings in github website

Comment: I used `npm run deploy` to deploy and the page is correctly charged in gh-pages branch

Answer (score 0):

this is how proper gh pages configuration works,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
 "homepage": "http://nazarenoalt.github.io/curriculum-maker/",
 "devDependencies": {
     "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
     "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
   }
```

then run `npm i` and then `npm run deploy` will gets website deployed

Comment: I get an "React-scripts not found", consider I'm creating a webpack enviroment and not using create-react-app.

This is my package.json currently: https://github.com/nazarenoalt/curriculum-maker/blob/main/package.json